# Adding a field to an existing XML file

Tags: xml, xml-parsing

I have this XML database with me and I want to add a new field to it. This kind of code runs into around 40k lines.

```
<instruction tag="L1" type="0" ">
    <fields i="1" S="1" Rn="1" imm3d="1" Rd="1" imm8d="1" />
    <attributes ThumbInts="1" hasL16version="1" Rd_eq_16_unpred="1" Rn_eq_13_unpred="1" Rd_eq_110_unpred="1" Rn_eq_25_unpred="1" />
    <unpredictable mask="00000" fill="000000">
        <fields g="1" gmmd="1" gmmsd="1" />
    </unpredictable>
    <unpredictable mask="000000" fill="0000000">
        <fields g="1" gmmd="1" gmmsd="1" />
    </unpredictable>
</instruction>
```

Now say I want to add a new attribute to this. There are around 3000 such instructions. For every instruction I want to add checker ="0 " attribute. How do I do it? Any leads? Sorry, I'm completely new to XML format.

Comment: In what environment? Java? From the command-line? Something else? Do you have access to an XSLT processor?

Comment: I want to do it from command -line. I don't have access to XSLT processor.

Comment: From what you've said, simple text processing -- finding every instance of `<fields ` and replacing it with `<fields checker="0" ` -- would do what you're asking for.  That's the DPH solution to the problem ("Desperate Perl Hacker").